# how to get used traits in php-class?

Tags: php, oop, traits

Is there any function in PHP (5.4) to get used traits as array or similar:

```
class myClass extends movingThings {
  use bikes, tanks;

  __construct() {
    echo 'I\'m using the two traits:' . ????; // bikes, tanks
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to make your question clearer. I think you're wanting to get bikes and tanks (your traits) from within the object or class. Similar to `get_class_methods()` except `get_class_traits()` which doesn't exist.

Comment: @Nik.... , why did you close it? You should not be using "close everything" approach when using `/review`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

To easily get the used traits you can call [class_uses()](http://php.net/class_uses)

```
$usedTraits = class_uses(MyClass);
// or
$usedTraits = class_uses($myObject);
```

## General recommendations

When checking for available functionality, I would generally recommend to use `interfaces`. To add default functionality to an interface you would use `traits`. This way you can also benefit from type hinting.

Force an object having functionality by implementing an interface and then use a trait to implement default code for that interface.

```
class MyClass 
    implements SomeInterface 
{
    use SomeTrait;
}
```

Then you can check the interface by;

```
$myObject = new MyClass();
if ($myObject instanceof SomeInterface) {
    //...
}
```

And still use type hinting;

```
function someFunction( SomeInterface $object )
{ 
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can write it yourself, by using the [ReflectionClass](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php)

```
$rc = new ReflectionClass('myClass');
$count = count($rc->getTraits());
```

Comment: Does getTraits() work the same as class_uses? Does it return the name of traits, used by class traits? Or traits, used by parent class?

Answer (score 8):

Just my 2 cents =)

```
in_array( "CLASS_NAME", class_uses($model) )
```

Or with PHP > 5.6

```
in_array( CLASS_NAME::class, class_uses($model) )
```

Answer (score 2):

`class-uses(<class>)` will get the immediate traits of `<class>` however it won't get all inherited traits by way of parent classes or traits of traits etc...

If you need to get absolutely all inherited traits on a class I would recommend reading the comments in the official docs here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-uses.php

Comment: @not_jagg_at_adecosystem shows a partial solution to this limitation.

Answer (score 2):

`class_uses` and `ReflectionClass->getTraits` will not work if you want to get traits from child class.

Example.

```php
trait A {}

class Mother {
    use A;
}

class Child extends Mother {}

var_dump(class_uses('Child'));  // empty array
var_dump(class_uses('Mother')); // has A
```

I have this problem so I write simple code for get all traits from classes.

```php
function all_class_uses($model)
{
    $class = new ReflectionClass($model);
    $traits = $class->getTraits();
    while($parent = $class->getParentClass()) {
        $traits += $class->getTraits();
        $class = $parent;
    }
    return array_combine(array_keys($traits), array_keys($traits));
}
```

Comment: I think `$traits += $class->getTraits();` in `while` loop should be `$traits += $parent->getTraits();`

Answer (score 1):

I wish that will be useful (thanks to Maurice for interface usage):

```
    interface IHaveHasTrait
    {
        public function has_trait($name);
    };

    trait THaveHasTrait
    {
        public function has_trait($name)
        {
            $classes = class_parents( $this );
            $classes[] = get_class( $this );
            foreach( $classes as $class ) {
                foreach( class_uses( $class ) as $t ) {
                    if( $t === $name ) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    trait TLinkedListItem
    {
        use THaveHasTrait;
        public $next;
        public $prev;
    };

    class A implements IHaveHasTrait
    {
        use TLinkedListItem;
        public $text;

        public function __construct( $_text )
        {
            $this->text = $_text;
        }
    };

    class B extends A{};

    class C extends B{};

    class LinkedList
    {
        public function insertItem( &$item, $position=0, $relative=false )
        {
            if( is_a( $item, 'IHaveHasTrait' ) ) {
                echo $item->has_trait( 'TLinkedListItem' ) ? 'has' : 'not';
            }
        }
    };

    $a = new C('a');
    $l = new LinkedList;
    $l->insertItem($a);
    ?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Short answer: you shouldn't. Traits are almost exactly copy and paste code. You don't NEED to know which traits are used, only on what the traits generate.

Answer I don't want to give: use [ReflectionClass::getTraits](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.gettraits.php). I'm not going to elaborate on this one.

Comment: Point of clarification: Are you saying you shouldn't use traits at all or shouldn't develop functionality that depends on what traits are implemented?

Comment: Traits are not just copy&paste. Why not use an information about traits like some kind of Metadata?

Comment: Imho traits should almost always be avoided, because it is just another way of tight coupling code.

Comment: @Ziumin In PHP they are almost copy and paste.  I chose my wording carefully.

Comment: @Levi Morrison I didn't say you that your answer is wrong. What about my second question?

Comment: @LeviMorrison Traits can be used as the oposite of "copy and paste", and to avoid redundant code.

Comment: @user247245 I mean that under the hood it is copy/paste. It has no special meaning, which is why you can't type-hint on it and that's why there isn't a `get_class_traits` function.

Comment: @Ziumin If you like programming with metadata you are either doing something cool or foolish. Since he isn't already familiar with Reflection, it's probably the latter.

Comment: @LeviMorrison, I'm doing something cool and it has nothing to do with reflection.